# ChartJs Skip few category, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm wondering if it is possible to skip one category in line graph? Because my dates are dynamic and there are datasets that don't have value for specific date.

As you can see below, I tried setting empty value on second slot on dataset # 1.

I'd appreciate any workaround and suggestions. I probably really need to use `x` and `y` coordinates as data if not possible.

I created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/8899/)

Code:

`var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-20"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Test 1',
          data: [12, , 19], //I tried skipping one value for date: 2018-01-09 here
          borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Test 2',
            data: [7, 11, 5],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]
  }
}`

`var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);`

**Update:** I switched to use `scatter` with `x` and `y` coordinates and I was able to achieve what I want. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/8930/).

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: Can't you just use 0 if there is no data?

Comment: Expecting something like **[`this`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e8n4xd4z/8901/)**?

Comment: I am expecting like this but it should not have any point on `16`: https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/8902/

Comment: @RubenPauwels Thanks for the suggestion of using 0. That would be another option to skip few labels.

Answer (score -1):

To skip you use `NaN` instead of 0. Using 0 will still draw the line down, then back up. You can see the example [here](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/interpolation-modes.html)

Comment: If I will replace `0` with `NaN`, the points are no longer connected to each other.

Comment: It skips the index. Just as what happens when you leave it blank. The issue is only you have 3 points. To not draw a line to the middle point means you only get the points for 1 and 3. Add a 4th data entry and you will see how it skips. Otherwise you can put 0, but 0 and skipping are two different things in the world of data.

Comment: In my example here : https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/8913/, I want the points `12, 5 and 19` to be connected to each other. But since I have `NaN` value before the point `19`, only the point `12` and `5` are connected. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No. But you said you wanted it skipped. Having a line to it isn’t skipping. If you want a line to it but to wrongfully represent data then use 0.